# Solving an Optimization (Find the minimum amount of time needed to get everyone up and down a mountain)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem goes like this (translated):

> There are n (n <= 25000) people at the bottom of a mountain, and everyone wants to go up, then down the mountain. There are 2 tour guides: one for helping a person go up the mountain, one for helping a person go down. Person i takes up(i) time to climb this mountain, and down(i) time to descend it.  However, each guide can only help 1 person at a time (which means at most 1 person can be climbing, and at most 1 person can be descending the mountain at any given time). Assume when the "up" guide reaches the top, he gets instantly teleported back to the bottom, as with the "down" guide. Find the least time it takes to get everyone up and back down the mountain. (People can congregate at the top of the mountain if necessary)

Here's a sample input for the problem, with annotations by me:

```
3 persons  
person 1: up=6 minutes, down=4 minutes  
person 2: up=8 minutes, down=1 minutes  
person 3: up=2 minutes, down=3 minutes
```

Output to the input:

> Minimum amount of time is 17. This is because If person 3 goes first, then person 1, and then person 2 (and this same order is
>   used for both the ascent and descent), this gives a total time of 17.

**I've tried coming up with a few algorithms, but here's what I have so far:**

An O(n! * n) algorithm: just permute the cows through all possible permutations using next_permutation

A greedy algorithm: I've sorted the people by decreasing descending time, and tried placing them together, but this did not result in the right solution.

**Other thoughts**

I'm turning to dynamic programming now, as according to the CLR, optimization problems are usually greedy or dynamic programming (this problem , I think, satisfies optimal substructure).

I've noticed that in the minimal solution, the "up" guide will have no rest until everyone is up the mountain. (So no gaps between person 1's ascent, person 2's ascent, etc..) Maybe the problem can be reduced to just minimizing the gaps between the descent times?

I'm having trouble picturing a state for this dynamic programming problem, ( I don't think it's single dimensional, because I don't think you can find the optimal solution for i person's just knowing the optimal solution for i-1 persons).

Could anyone help?

Comment: just an intuition that others might use : it might be better to think about that problem in another way : minimize idle time of the down guide (up guide is never stalled).

Comment: For the guide problem, here is what I was thinking, the down guide should take people at the top who has the shortest down time. The up guide should also take the person with the shortest up time, except it shouldn't take a person up that take less time going down than going up unless the time difference can be made up with the queue of people waiting at the top or there is no other choice but to take people that take less time going down than up.

Comment: I guess it kind of depends on the number of people and how varied the times are.  If you don't mind the queue at the top, the having the down guide take the longest time person first may be better.  Interesting thought exercise.

Comment: Cows turned into people?  Maybe posting this during the contest is not the best idea. . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to the n-job 2-machine flow shop problem with the makespan objective (n/2/F/C<sub>max</sub>). [Johnson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Shop_Scheduling) finds an exact solution.

Answer (score -1):

Only descending guide idle time matters really. And after giving it some thought, I think the main issue here is picking the first person to climb up, because the time of the first climber is a sure delay for descending guide.

Solution could be to pick the one with lowest `up(i)` out of those that have `down(i) > up(i)` and then for climbing you prioritize everyone with `down(i) > up(i)`, then `down(i) = up(i)`, then all the rest. For descending you simply prioritize people with longest down(i).

What this achieves is:

1. You delay the descending guide the least at start
2. You keep him busy all the time after that

Comment: "Only descending guide idle time matters really. And after giving it some thought, I think the main issue here is picking the first person to climb up, because the time of the first climber is a sure delay for descending guide." -> This pretty much means that a the up guide is always working, right?

Comment: I've tried implementing this algorithm, but it doesn't quite work. Although the idea of keeping him busy sounds about right..

Comment: Would you provide an example of what exactly doesn't work? And for which data sample it gives wrong result?